# How to create a slurm queue for the headnode

Tags: cluster

Is there a way to create a SLURM queue that runs on the headnode?

I'd like to be able to do this as a first level testing queue sort of, before trying to run on multiple nodes.

I've tried stuff like:

```
create PartitionName=matt AllowGroups=ALL Default=yes State=UP Nodes=dena
```

(where dena is the name of the cluster)

I'm going to try defining dena0 in the dns, so perhaps dena[0] may work?  Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved this (also looks like I had done this before and simply forgot)

In .../etc/slurm.conf,

I added my headnode as a node,

```
NodeName=dena Procs=16
```

Restarted everything, and then was able to assign it.  Pretty simple I suppose.

Comment: I was wrong about this.  It does allow slurm to create a partition on that node, but that node still must be running a slurm_client.  I'm not sure how to do this on a generic system.  I managed to do it via Bright Management Cluster software I have.